# Ground Plane Stage rotate child object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project I have a Ground Plane Stage with an child object. Now I want to rotate this object with a UI Button. If i hold the button down it should rotate and if I release the button the rotation should stop. Unfortunately I´m not able to do this.

This is my script:

```
public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 45f;
    public bool isPressed = false;

    public void TogglePressed(bool value)
    {
        isPressed = !isPressed;
    } //edit added missing Brace

    void Update()
    {
        if (isPressed)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I added `Event Trigger` with `Pointer Down` and `Pointer Up` to the button.
The script is attached to my gameObject and the `TogglePressed`function is linked to `Pointer Down` with the checkbox checked and to `Pointer Up`, here checkbox is not checked.

If I test it in Unity and click the button, the inspector shows that it works, but if I upload it to my phone, there is no rotation of the object.

**EDIT:**

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown()`

```
void Update()
{
    if (isPressed && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // Same Code
    }
```

}

`Input.GetButtonDown()`

```
void Update()
{
    if(isPressed && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        //Same Code
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

This is my script i use now:

```
public class RoatateObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 45f;

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
           transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont know exactly if pointerdown is recognized on phones, do you have tried Input.GetMouseButtonDown() (also trigger on phones)?

maybe to speed up your testing try [unity remote](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html) to test local instead of uploading to your phone

Comment: if i use `Input.GetMouseButtonDown()` i need to use an `OnClick` Event right?

Comment: no you don't need to use OnClick: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html
or
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html

Comment: If i use `Input.GetButtonDown()` nothing happens, not even my `Debug.Log` is shown. if i use `Pointer Down` my `Debug.Log` is shown. So i think `Pointer Down` is recognized on phones.

Comment: have you also tried GetMouseButtonDown? or just GetButtonDown()?

Comment: I tried both. Unfortunately with both ways there was no `Debug.Log`.

Comment: could you please copy the code of them, how you use them?

Comment: see my Edits. I used Fire1 and named the button to rotate also Fire1

Comment: ok thank you, 
please delete isPressed from the if-statement, i think this will never toggle anymore. (based on lack of knowledge of your other code parts).

Comment: but now everytime i tap on the screen my object rotates. how can i stop this?

Comment: ok so basically, the rotation works as you wanted it to.
The problem now is to get it started just, when you press the button and i would realize it with an OnClick-EventHandler or a Listener, could you please update your code? do you have updated the source of Fire1 or what ever you use?

Ok the Way i would use it is obsolete so please have a look at https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.html

Comment: thanks.you could limit the access using Mobile Input -> position https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/MobileInput.html
you could check if the position is on your button and if yes, start rotation.